# Execute cmd command in Java Applet

Tags: java, applet

I'm trying to execute cmd command in Java applet, I tried this code

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
public class execute extends Applet{
String output="";
public void init(){ 
try {
// Execute command
String command = "MYCMDCOMMAND";
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
// Get the input stream and read from it
InputStream in = child.getInputStream();
int c= in.read();
while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
output =output+((char)c);
}
in.close();
}   
catch (IOException e) {
}
System.out.println(output);
}
public void paint(Graphics g){
g.drawString(output,60,100);
}
}
```

And then wrote this html file and saved it in the same directory:

```
<html>
<head><title>Applet</title>
<body>
<applet code="execute.class",height="200" width="200">
</body>
</html>
```

What I'm trying to do here is to run the ls shell command in an applet and display the results.

The code compiles with no errors. But when I open the html file in the browser, I just get a gray square.

Is this because of security issues that I don't get anything? Or is it because of an error in the code?

Comment: I don't know if what you're trying to do is legal for applets, especially unsigned ones, given their sandbox restrictions Also, your code doesn't appear to be respecting Swing's threading rules. Also, your lack of error catching is quite dangerous.

Comment: The short answer is **DON`T**. The whole point of applets is you have a very restricted set of rights on the end user system, executing external commands is most defiantly up there as a massive security issue. Use a dedicated application and something like [Java Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/) to deploy it. You are still going to have security issues, but these provide a cleaner solution for clients

Comment: 1) *"Is this because of security issues that I don't get anything?"*  The answer to that would be reported in the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml). 2) As a general tip, change `catch (IOException e) {
}` to `catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();
}`  3) The HTML is malformed, check it using a [validation service](http://validator.w3.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You must be careful about some things.

1. You have to Copy & paste your Html file to .bin file after you compiled
2. Your HTML file name is Applet and your class name execute.class so it means you do not have package if u have you must save your html file as "PACKAGENAME/execute.class",
3. At Control Panel / Java you must disable Security